# Application class annotated with @HiltAndroidApp has to be defined in an android application project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, clean-architecture, modular

I am having an Application class already annotated with @HiltAndroidApp but it is in a different module than App module, i needed it to be in the framework module so i can access it from my Service class .
what can be the issue here knowing i have all the Hilt dependencies added to the Framework module gradle .

Answer (score 0):

i ended up  using this in my App module

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : FrameWorkApp()
```

and this in the framework module

```
open class FrameWorkApp  : Application() {
}
```

and in my appModule

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFollowMe(@ApplicationContext app: Context): FrameWorkApp  
= app as FrameWorkApp
```